# Shareaholic Icons Not Being Displayed Fully

Tags: javascript, css, plugins, share

I've decided to use Shareaholic as my share method on my blog but the icons aren't showing up in full.

Here's what it looks like on the Shareaholic website:

[image]

But when I load it in my webpage it displays as:

[image]

Does anyone know a fix for this so that it shows all of the icons?

Here is my code for anyone who thinks it's relevant:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//dsms0mj1bbhn4.cloudfront.net/assets/pub/shareaholic.js' data-shr-siteid='c10bab3e6be269bc413ba1a0473965ed' data-cfasync='false' async='async'></script>
```

+

```
<div class='shareaholic-canvas' data-app='share_buttons' data-app-id='24261098'></div>
```

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: Code? As I'm using the default code provided by Shareaholic I'm not aware that this is a coding error, so I haven't posted any.

Comment: I don't exactly know how it works, but then maybe you haven't edited your links properly? (I suppose you must edit them in their website, or somewherE)

Comment: I have edited the code on the Shareaholic website and they show that it should look like Image 1. They then provide the code and I put it in the website, but it looks like Image 2. Does anyone know why?